# Should a Get-Ajax request change data on the server?

Tags: ajax, database, server, request

I read documents online. They say that 
A GET-Ajax request is used for getting data from the server. 
A POST-Ajax request is used for change data on the server. 
But why is it?

A Get-Ajax request can change the data on the server **TOO**, right?

Why should only the POST-Ajax request change the data?
Is it because of a security reason or something? Please explain to me

Answer (score 1):

GET and POST are different methods for web requests that provide different features/describe different intentions for programmers and APIs. You are correct that, technically speaking, if you want to do some other CRUD operation on the server when using a GET request, you can. Most would probably argue that this is not a good idea, in part for security/performance features that either method provides. Example: GET requests can be cached, POST cannot.

More on that here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: is there any security/performance feature apart from caching?